# React bootstrap overlay rootclose not working

Tags: reactjs, overlay, react-bootstrap

I followed exactly the same style as the overlay example in the bootstrap website, and on the website, when I tried to add rootclose, it does not work properly(overlay does not dismiss on click on other places of screen), and same for my own work

```
const Example = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { show: true };
  },

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  },

  render() {
    const style = {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: '#EEE',
      boxShadow: '0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      border: '1px solid #CCC',
      borderRadius: 3,
      marginLeft: -5,
      marginTop: 5,
      padding: 10
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ height: 100, position: 'relative' }}>
        <Button ref="target" onClick={this.toggle}>
          I am an Overlay target
        </Button>

        <Overlay
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
          placement="right"
          container={this}
          rootclose
          target={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.target)}
        >
          <div style={style}>
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
          </div>
        </Overlay>
      </div>
    );`enter code here`
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, mountNode);
```

Comment: Try `rootClose` instead of `rootclose`.

Comment: Had same problem and realized it was because I was using `onTouchTap` instead of `onClick` on the trigger button.

Answer (score 2):

Camelcase it. And supply the boolean.

`rootClose={true}`